# Windows Opening file:///C:/Users/David on Startup

Tags: windows-8.1

When I load up Windows 8.1, it asks me:

> How would you like to open this type of file?

Then gives me options starting with Google Chrome and Avast Safe Browser, and I thought maybe a program I installed was opening a webpage, but when I clicked chrome, it brought up this:

[image]

Why is Windows opening this file on startup, and how can I stop it from happening?

Comment: Does it happen if you boot to Safe Mode?

Comment: @Ramhound Will test.

Comment: Have you checked your Startup folder? You can type `shell:startup` in Run window to open the folder and see if there unwanted files inside.

Comment: @Chinggis6 - Learned something new today ... never knew about `shell:startup`.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chinggis6 Nevermind. Although I thought that would be what was causing this problem, it is still happening after I removed ***all shortcuts*** from `shell:startup`

Comment: @Ramhound No, when booting into safe mode, this prompt does not show up

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice - Update your question

Answer (score 2):

You might also try to run `shell:Common Startup` for system-wide Startup folder.

Apart from that check Startup tab of `msconfig` (System Configuration window).

If nothing help utilize the [AutoRuns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) an excellent tool by Sysinternals (a Microsoft subsidiary) that is just meant for that, what locates and conveniently sorts out different types of startup applications by tabs:

[image]